# Should I block a hole in my door to prevent noise/heat/cold issues?

Tags: doors, air-conditioning, sound-proofing

I have 3 doors in my house that were modified for our cat to be able to move inside the house when the doors are closed, so we wont have to get up and open them for him all the time (all the doors are inside the house).

As the cat is no longer with us for a few years now, and we have a new baby, I wonder if this modification (just a normal hole in the door) allows more sound/air to go through the door and making the door less efficient in blocking voices/noise/hot/cold air.

The doors are regular wooden inner doors.
Should I do something about this? If so, what will be the easiest fix for this to maximize noise/air canceling ?

Note, I don't really mind the aesthetics of the issue, just worried about sound and hot/cold air being wasted on this hole.

[image: Drawing of door with the cat door indicated]

Comment: Unless you have a room that you need to keep at a dramatically different temperature, I don't see it being a concern. Is there an actual problem you are encountering?

Comment: Cropped the image for viewing convenience

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a room that you need to keep at a dramatically different temperature, I don't see it being a concern.

Presuming you are heating/cooling rooms on both side of all doors, there is no heat/cooling concern here.

The noise concern might be valid, but if it is not currently an issue, there is no real reason to do repair the hole where the cat door is.

Answer (score 0):

If the undercut on those doors is minimal and your return ducts (don't) suck or are non-existent, then your furnace loves them there for their lowering the static pressure.

Cut little squares of 1" or 2" sheet foam to an exact fit; cold air and noise: done.

I hope you like pink.

Comment: can paper over the foam and paint over the paper.